# Combine results from regex to make x,y pairs

Tags: python, regex, geospatial

I'm trying to take a string output from my database, run a regex on the string, and then combine some of the results from the regex. I need to put multiple results together to create a neat csv output I can pull into R. (The real thing I'm stumped on is storing individual results as separate variables from the regex-- that's the larger thing I can't figure out. Anyways...)

This is an example of the string that I'm trying to clean.

```
LINESTRING (-1 -2, -2 3.8, -1 5.6, 0 -3, 1.5 3.3, 2 -23, 6 -12)
```

I want the output to look like this:

```
x,y
-1,-2
-2,3.8
-1,5.6
0,-3
1.5,3.3
2,-23
6,-12
```

Bonus if we can make it look like this (optimal way for the segments function in R):

```
x1,y1,x2,y2
-1,-2,-2,3.8
-2,3.8,-1,5.6
-1,5.6,0,-3
0,-3,1.5,3.3
1.5,3.3,2,-23
2,-23,6,-12
6,-12,6,-12
```

Here is the code I have:

```
import re

file_name = 'linestring.dat'

lines = open(file_name)
data = lines.read()
print("x, y")
regex = re.compile("([-+]?\d*\.\d+|[-+]?\d+)")
clean_data = regex.findall(data)
for line in clean_data:
    print line
```

This prints each regex results individually. I'm stumped on how to iterate over the results and assign each result to a variable to make the x,y pair I can print.

Thanks for your help and I hope my question is helpful to other R and Python folks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this can be done without re, for example if this is your string:

```
l = "LINESTRING (-1 -2, -2 3.8, -1 5.6, 0 -3, 1.5 3.3, 2 -23, 6 -12)"
```

grab the numbers from between the parenthesis and put them as string pairs into a list, then iterate through them to get your output, replacing the space with a comma

```
data = l.split('(', 1)[1].split(')')[0].split(',')
for d in data:
    print d.strip().replace(' ',',')
```

to get your your optimal way for R, you can take advantage of the index number in that list:

```
for k,d in enumerate(data):
    first = data[k].strip().replace(' ',',').strip()
    try:
        second = data[k+1].strip().replace(' ',',')
    except IndexError:
        # this is the last line, use the first value as second (maybe?)
        second = first
    print "%s,%s" % (first, second)
```

Comment: So this answer does more than @Hackaholic 's answer. This answer also can handle the preceding LINESTRING text, which is something I need it to do. After more testing, this is a better solution for me. Thanks brobas for helping me with this.

Answer (score 1):

1st solution:

```
>>> >>> my_string = "-1 -2, -2 3.8, -1 5.6, 0 -3, 1.5 3.3, 2 -23, 6 -12"
>>> my_list = map(str.split,my_string.split(', '))
>>> my_list
[['-1', '-2'], ['-2', '3.8'], ['-1', '5.6'], ['0', '-3'], ['1.5', '3.3'], ['2', '-23'], ['6', '-12']]
```

it will look as you expect, if you join with \n and print it:

```
>>> print("\n".join(map(",".join,my_list)))
-1,-2
-2,3.8
-1,5.6
0,-3
1.5,3.3
2,-23
6,-12
```

2nd solution:

```
>>> my_list
[['-1', '-2'], ['-2', '3.8'], ['-1', '5.6'], ['0', '-3'], ['1.5', '3.3'], ['2', '-23'], ['6', '-12']]
>>> for i in range(len(my_list)):
...     if i == len(my_list)-1:
...         print(",".join(my_list[i]+my_list[i]))
...     else:print(",".join(my_list[i]+my_list[i+1]))
... 
-1,-2,-2,3.8
-2,3.8,-1,5.6
-1,5.6,0,-3
0,-3,1.5,3.3
1.5,3.3,2,-23
2,-23,6,-12
6,-12,6,-12
```

Comment: A lot of great answers. They all work great. Thanks for helping me solve this!

Answer (score 0):

Using your regexp, you could use zip to get your first form:

```
>>> for x1,y1 in zip(clean_data[::2],clean_data[1::2]):
...   print ",".join([x1,y1])
... 
-1,-2
-2,3.8
-1,5.6
0,-3
1.5,3.3
2,-23
6,-12
```

And for the second (I am afraid that this is not very pythonic, nor efficient though):

```
>>> for x1,y1,x2,y2 in zip(clean_data[::2],clean_data[1::2],clean_data[2::2],clean_data[3::2]):
...  print ",".join([x1,y1,x2,y2])
... 
-1,-2,-2,3.8
-2,3.8,-1,5.6
-1,5.6,0,-3
0,-3,1.5,3.3
1.5,3.3,2,-23
2,-23,6,-12
```

Comment: @Hackaholic it was indeed. Forgot the `::2` step… Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the `clean_data` looks something like this:

```
['-1', '-2', '-2', '3.8', '-1', '5.6', '0', '-3', '1.5', '3.3', '2', '-23', '6', '-12']
```

in order to join the elements in pairs, we can do the following:

```
l = zip(clean_data[0::2], clean_data[1::2])
```

This means *pair up the odd indexed elements with the corresponding even ones*. Now you can print them out or do further processes:. For instance:

```
>>> for i in l:
    print(i)


('-1', '-2')
('-2', '3.8')
('-1', '5.6')
('0', '-3')
('1.5', '3.3')
('2', '-23')
('6', '-12')
```

Answer (score 0):

In R

```
x <- "-1 -2, -2 3.8, -1 5.6, 0 -3, 1.5 3.3, 2 -23, 6 -12"

xx <- Filter(Negate(is.na), as.numeric(strsplit(x, "[\\s+|,]", perl = TRUE)[[1]]))

do.call('rbind', lapply(seq(1, length(xx) - 2, by = 2),
                        function(ii) xx[ii:(ii + 3)]))

#      [,1]  [,2] [,3]  [,4]
# [1,] -1.0  -2.0 -2.0   3.8
# [2,] -2.0   3.8 -1.0   5.6
# [3,] -1.0   5.6  0.0  -3.0
# [4,]  0.0  -3.0  1.5   3.3
# [5,]  1.5   3.3  2.0 -23.0
# [6,]  2.0 -23.0  6.0 -12.0
```

Comment: This is a great solution to my problem within R. Thanks for answering the question in R.

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you need to use regex, try the following:

```
import re
s = r'LINESTRING (-1 -2, -2 3.8, -1 5.6, 0 -3, 1.5 3.3, 2 -23, 6 -12)'

numeric = re.findall(r'LINESTRING \(([^\)]+)', s)
numbers = list(re.findall(r'([.+\-\d]+)', numeric[0]))

for i in range(0,len(numbers),2):
    ns = numbers[i:i+4]
    if len(ns) == 2: ns *= 2
    print(tuple(map(float, ns)))

'''
(-1.0, -2.0, -2.0, 3.8)
(-2.0, 3.8, -1.0, 5.6)
(-1.0, 5.6, 0.0, -3.0)
(0.0, -3.0, 1.5, 3.3)
(1.5, 3.3, 2.0, -23.0)
(2.0, -23.0, 6.0, -12.0)
(6.0, -12.0, 6.0, -12.0)
'''
```